# Pandas Groupby and divide the dataset into subgroups based on user input and label numbers to each subgroup

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

Here is my data:

```
ID  Mnth Amt    Flg
B   1   10             0
B   2   12             0
B   3   14             0
B   4   41             0
B   5   134            0
B   6   14             0
B   7   134            0
B   8   134            0
B   9   12             0
B   10  41             0
B   11  4              0
B   12  14             0
B   12  14             0
A   1   34             0
A   2   22             0
A   3   56             0
A   4   129            0
A   5   40             0
A   6   20             0
A   7   58             0
A   8   123            0
```

If I give 3 as input, my output should be:

```
ID  Mnth Amt Flg Level_Flag
B   1   10  0   0
B   2   12  0   1
B   3   14  0   1
B   4   41  0   1
B   5   134 0   2
B   6   14  0   2
B   7   134 0   2
B   8   134 0   3
B   9   12  0   3
B   10  41  0   3
B   11  4   0   4
B   12  14  0   4
B   12  14  0   4
A   1   34  0   0
A   2   22  0   0
A   3   56  0   1
A   4   129 0   1
A   5   40  0   1
A   6   20  0   2
A   7   58  0   2
A   8   123 0   2
```

So basically I want to divide the data into subgroups with 3 rows in each subgroup from bottom up and label those subgroups as mentioned in level_flag column. I have IDs like A,C and so on. So I want to do this for each group of ID.Thanks in Advance.

Edit :- I want the same thing to be done after grouping it by ID

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with "3 subgroups"? I see 4 unique flags in `Level_Flag`

Comment: I want 'n' subgroups with 3 rows in each subgroup. If I give 4 as input. It should give me 'n' subgroups with 4 rows in each subgroups.
Sorry I am new to stackoverflow. I dont know how to post the data correctly.

Comment: @Erfan He wants each subgroup to have three members.  So there could be 10000 numbers in `Level_Flag` but none will appear more than three times.

Comment: Exactly, If I give 4 then the dataset should be divided into 'n' subgroups based on total no. of records in dataset. But each subgroup should have 4 rows with labels mentioned in Level_Flag column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we decide the unique numbers `nums` by dividing the length of your df by `n`. Then we `repeat` those numbers `n` times. Finally we reverse the array and chop it of at the `length of df` and reverse it one more time.

```
def create_flags(d, n):
    nums = np.ceil(len(d) / n)
    level_flag = np.repeat(np.arange(nums), n)[::-1][:len(d)][::-1]
    
    return level_flag

df['Level_Flag'] = df.groupby('ID')['ID'].transform(lambda x: create_flags(x, 3))

   ID  Mnth  Amt  Flg  Level_Flag
0   B     1   10    0         0.0
1   B     2   12    0         1.0
2   B     3   14    0         1.0
3   B     4   41    0         1.0
4   B     5  134    0         2.0
5   B     6   14    0         2.0
6   B     7  134    0         2.0
7   B     8  134    0         3.0
8   B     9   12    0         3.0
9   B    10   41    0         3.0
10  B    11    4    0         4.0
11  B    12   14    0         4.0
12  B    12   14    0         4.0
```

---

To remove the incomplete rows, use `GroupBy.transform`:

```
m = df.groupby(['ID', 'Level_Flag'])['Level_Flag'].transform('count').ge(3)
df = df[m]

   ID  Mnth  Amt  Flg  Level_Flag
1   B     2   12    0         1.0
2   B     3   14    0         1.0
3   B     4   41    0         1.0
4   B     5  134    0         2.0
5   B     6   14    0         2.0
6   B     7  134    0         2.0
7   B     8  134    0         3.0
8   B     9   12    0         3.0
9   B    10   41    0         3.0
10  B    11    4    0         4.0
11  B    12   14    0         4.0
12  B    12   14    0         4.0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot -Erfan This is exactly what I am  looking for.
But is there a way to remove those incomplete rows where we have 0.By  Incomplete I mean - to remove where the level_flag is not repeated 3 times (or n times as given by user)

Comment: Hi @Erfan can you help me with removing the incomplete rows?

Comment: Thanks a lot. @Erfan. :)